# Variables not incrementing

Tags: python, python-3.x, camera, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2

So, I'm using a raspberry pi and trying to make a security camera device. I'm trying to catalog every photo taken, with a new .jpg file for each pic and i think have that part down but the variable using to name each photo wont increment. So I have one file that keeps getting replaced with each picture taken. I'm very very confused. Here's code, any help is appreciated.

```
#defines camera function
def camera(pic_num):
    with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
        camera.start_preview()
        time.sleep(5)
        pic_num += 1
        camera.capture('/home/pi/locker_photos/' + str(pic_num) + '.jpg')
        print (pic_num)
        camera.stop_preview()
```

Comment: where are you calling `camera`? Where is `pic_num` defined?

Comment: You don't return the updated pic_num so it is garbage collected when the function exits.  Use return pic_num at the end, and call the function with pic_num=camera(pic_num) so you catch the updated number as well.  See "The return Statement" at http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions.htm for an example.

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because `pic_num` is being assigned as a **local variable** inside your `camera` function. The easiest way to resolve your issue would be to increment `pic_num` outside of the `camera` function from wherever you are calling `camera`.

If I may, here's a smarter way of doing this naming that doesn't involve keeping track of a counter:

```
#defines camera function
def camera():
    PHOTOS_DIR = '/home/pi/locker_photos/'
    with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
        camera.start_preview()
        time.sleep(5)
        # Get the next highest number from the files that already exist
        pic_num = max(int(os.path.splitext(f)[0]) for f in os.listdir(PHOTOS_DIR)) + 1
        camera.capture(PHOTOS_DIR + str(pic_num) + '.jpg')
        print (pic_num)
        camera.stop_preview()
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't actually recommend using the `while True:` statement, but something like this should work:

```
def camera(pic_num):
    with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
        camera.start_preview()
        time.sleep(5)
        camera.capture('/home/pi/locker_photos/' + str(pic_num) + '.jpg')
        print (pic_num)
        camera.stop_preview()
...
while True:
    pic_num=pic_num+1
    #now pic_num will be a unique number each time you call camera
    camera(pic_num)
```

Or

```
for pic_num in range(some_finite_number):
    #still will be unique
    camera(pic_num)
```

Comment: this is an elaboration on @hfaran's answer