# How incrementor function is not incrementing the num variable?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am  unable to understand please help me with same. I just want to know why num variable is not incrementing on calling a function incrementor? i guess output should be (100,100), Instead it is showing (100,0)

```
def main():
    counter=Counter()
    num=0
    for x in range(0,100):
        incrementor(counter,num)
    return (counter.count, num)
def incrementor(c, num):
    c.count+=1
    num+=1

class Counter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.count=0

print(main())
```

Comment: Your `num` parameter in `incrementor()` is local to that method. And it *is* incremented, except it is immediately thrown away. Did you mean `return num+1`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Variables not incrementing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32173077/variables-not-incrementing)

Comment: Another dup: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/575196/why-can-a-function-modify-some-arguments-as-perceived-by-the-caller-but-not-oth

Comment: Ah, yes, there is also: Mandatory link to [Ned Batchelder](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Comment: @quamrana Sorry but i didnt understood, every time loop executes is goes to function incrementor then it incraments num. then why it returns 0 only.

Comment: But `num` is not returned from `incrementor()`. You *can* return it as I said above by using: `return num + 1`

Comment: ohhhh! I got it now. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have code like this:

```py
class Counter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.count = 0

def incrementor(c, num):
    c.count += 1
    num += 1

def main():
    counter = Counter()
    num = 0
    incrementor(counter, num)
    return (counter.count, num)

print(main())
```

What is actually happening at the call site: `incrementor(counter, num)` is this:

**WARNING:** PSEUDO CODE AHEAD

```py
counter = Counter()
num = 0

c = counter
num = num

call incrementor
```

The above is bizarre and easy to misunderstand, so I'll rephrase it:

**WARNING:** PSEUDO CODE AHEAD

```py
def incrementor(c, n):
    c.count += 1
    n += 1

counter = Counter()
num = 0

c = counter
n = num

call incrementor
```

Now where I have put `n = num` the `n` is the name of the variable used inside `incrementor()`, which shows `n` is a *different* variable, which gets incremented inside the function, but thrown away when it returns.

So, in order to do what it seems you want to do you need to do this:

```py
class Counter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.count = 0

def incrementor(c, num):
    c.count += 1
    return num + 1

def main():
    counter = Counter()
    num = 0
    for x in range(0, 100):
        num = incrementor(counter, num)
    return (counter.count, num)

print(main())
```

Output:

```
(100, 100)
```